# Problem cloning gitolite on Windows

Tags: git, version-control, gitolite

I use Windows 7. I am working with a project that is using Redmine and a Gitolite repo. I gave the admin my id_rsa.pub, and he added it to the list of authenticated users. However, I am unable to clone the repo. When I use:

```
git clone git@foo:bar
```

I am asked for a password. I have no idea what to put. I tried my public key, private key, password for Redmine, etc, but nothing works.

Apparently, if I was using Linux this would just work, without asking for a password.

I tried it with both the command line, and msysgit (GitGUI), but it didn't work.

Is there some trick to this?

**Update**: This looks like it might be useful: http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/05/06/git-ssh-putty-github-unfuddle-the-kitchen-sink.aspx, but I don't see where in the msysgit installation process I can specify that it must use PLink as the SSH executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

msysgit will generate public keys for you. Just generate one, then send it to the admin, and everything works.